# How to remove certain entries (using regex) from array?

Tags: php, arrays, filter

I'm coding a scraper like the Facebook one to get info from a given url. Im just one step to  finish the basic functionality. The problem so far is to remove useless images.
For example, when i run some random url, i get all this images:

```
Scraper Object
(
    [url] => http://buzz.money.cnn.com/2012/07/23/spain-italy-short-selling/?iid=HP_Highlight
    [title] => Spain and Italy ban short selling  - The Buzz  - Investment and Stock Market News
    [description] => The Euronext 100 stock index falls sharply on renewed concerns about Spain.    Securities regulators in Spain and Italy both instituted short-selling bans Monday as financial markets tumbled.    The move is designed to limit the downward pressure
    [imageUrls] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://cnnmoneybuzzblog.files.wordpress.com/2012/07/chart_ws_index_euronext100_201272310932-09.png
            [1] => http://i.cdn.turner.com/money/.e1m/img/5.0/data/feargreed/scale.316x95.png
            [2] => http://i2.cdn.turner.com/money/.element/img/5.0/sections/contributors/ben_rooney_130.jpg
            [3] => http://i2.cdn.turner.com/money/.element/img/5.0/sections/contributors/catherine_tymkiw.02.jpg
            [4] => http://i2.cdn.turner.com/money/.element/img/5.0/sections/contributors/paul_lamonica.02.jpg
            [5] => http://i2.cdn.turner.com/money/.element/img/5.0/sections/contributors/hibah_yousuf.02.jpg
            [6] => http://i2.cdn.turner.com/money/.element/img/5.0/sections/contributors/maureen_farrell.02.jpg
            [7] => http://i2.cdn.turner.com/money/.element/img/5.0/sections/contributors/ben_rooney.02.jpg
            [8] => http://i.cdn.turner.com/money/.element/img/4.0/services/button_login.gif
            [9] => http://www.bizographics.com/collect/?fmt=gif&pid=311
            [10] => http://pixel.quantserve.com/pixel/p-5dyPa639IrgIw.gif
            [11] => http://i.cdn.turner.com/money/.element/img/1.0/misc/1.gif
            [12] => http://buzz.money.cnn.com/2012/07/23/spain-italy-short-selling/?iid=HP_Highlight//pixel.quantserve.com/pixel/p-18-mFEk4J448M.gif?labels=%2Clanguage.en%2Ctype.wpcom%2Cposttag.bonds%2Cposttag.dow%2Cposttag.ibex%2Cposttag.italy%2Cposttag.lehman%2Cposttag.milan%2Cposttag.nasdaq%2Cposttag.sp-500%2Cposttag.short-selling%2Cposttag.spain%2Cposttag.stock%2Cposttag.yields%2Cvip.cnnmoneybuzzblog
            [13] => http://stats.wordpress.com/b.gif?v=noscript
        )

)
```

I just need to find a way to remove all those images ending in .gif or .png and just let the .jpg inside the array, so the user can take a look and select proper one for the article.

I've tried some array functions but i think this need some regex magic for it to work in almost any url given.

P.S. I can access all array data using `$info->url`, `$info->description` and so. Just need to filter that array and it will be ready.

Comment: *Off topic:* CNN Money Buzz Blog shows up in a lot of the spam I get...

Comment: I had a customer who loves linking to Money CNN. I just made my part coding the scraper :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without using regex:

```
foreach ($objects_array as $obj){
  foreach($obj->imageUrls as $key => $img){
    if(substr($img, -4) === '.gif' || substr($img, -4) === '.png'){
      unset($key);
    }
  }
}
```

and using regex:

```
$pt = '/gif$|png$/';
foreach ($objects_array as $obj){
  foreach($obj->imageUrls as $key => $img){
    $res = preg_match($pt, $img);
    if($res){
      unset($key);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You going to hate me my friend, but, it doesn't show any errors but it still shows all the image files including gifs and pngs. Actually, i removed the first foreach because there is only one object. $info only gathers info from one url. I have $info->url, $info->title, $info->description and the array $info->imageUrls. What could be wrong?

Comment: @Richard-MX of course I'm not going to hate you ;) a quick guess (since I don't have you code) try to replace: `unset($key);` with: `unset($info->imageUrls[$key]);`

Comment: **It's working!** Thanks amigo :), if you came to Cancun one day (yes, there are programmers here too :P) drinks are on me!

Answer (score 3):

Try array_filter:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

The callback function should be a very basic function that returns false if your regex matches .png or .gif.

Answer (score 0):

You could filter after the array is built:

```
function only_jpgs($url){
    return substr($url, -4) == '.jpg' ? $url : false;
}

$info->imageUrls = array_filter($info->imageUrls, "only_jpgs");
```

But you probably should filter out the images before you build the array.

Comment: I can't get this one to work my friend. When you call "only_jpgs" from the array_filter, how does the function now what's the $url? Im getting this error **array_filter() expects parameter 2 to be a valid callback, function 'only_jpgs' not found or invalid function name** using it like that. Thanks.

Comment: @Richard-MX If you can't cut and paste I can't help you.